# Do all versions of the Jaguar XJ (2010 onwards) come with dual view screens?

Tags: navigation, jaguar

This is a feature on Jaguar cars:

http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/ay5PZvM_460sa.gif

But does it come as standard on all XJ models 2010 onwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though it does come standard on the 2010+ Jaguar XJ. This is a system built by Bosch Car Multimedia division. It was first slated for the luxury Mercedes S-Class, so the XJ is the second car to get it. In [this article dated May 2010](http://www.automotive-eetimes.com/en/jaguar-equips-xj-model-with-bosch-head-unit.html?cmp_id=7&news_id=222900814), EE Times talks about it being in the XJ:

> Bosch has developed a head unit that will be first introduced onto the market in the new Jaguar XJ. Centerpiece of the head unit is a touch-screen with a diagonal of 8 inches (20 cm). The unit offers some innovative features including 'Dual View' functionality.

Here on the [Jaguar website](http://www.jaguar.com/jaguar-range/xj/xj-models/xj-supersport-lwb.html), they talk of it being standard equipment on the XJ:

> With the 8 inch dual video screens, your front seat passenger can enjoy completely different content on their screen.

This is located within the **Standard Features** section of their page describing the XJ, so one can assume that not only is it standard equipment on all XJs, it has been there since 2010 and continues to be there.